# How do I dynamically change the content in an iframe using jquery?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I was wondering if it is possible to have a site with an iframe and some jquery code that changes the iframe content every 30 seconds. The content is in different webpages.

Something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var array = new array();
        array[0] = 'http://webPage1.com';
        array[1] = 'http://webPage2.com';
        // And so on.
        // Do something here to change the iframe every 30 second
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="frame"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The bottom of the post is not showing, but it was basic html with an iframe.

Comment: @Audun: i fixed it for you; next time, highlight everything and use the code button. Also, spacing is cool.

Comment: things like `http://webPage1.com` need to be in quotes! `//` will make a comment!

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var locations = ["http://webPage1.com", "http://webPage2.com"];
        var len = locations.length;
        var iframe = $('#frame');
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
            iframe.attr('src', locations[++i % len]);
        }, 30000);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="frame"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The [++i % len] as a way to iterate through the array with recycling is brilliant! That taught me a new pattern! Thanks!

Comment: Note that inside the setInterval function you don't need to use "$(iframe)." but rather you can directly "iframe." cause you have already created iframe as a jQuery object few lines above. Cheers.

Comment: How if the interval set up dynamically changed?

Comment: Use setTimeout instead then

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to change where the iframe points to and not the actual content inside the iframe, you would just need to change the `src` attribute.

```
 $("#myiframe").attr("src", "newwebpage.html");
```

Comment: load() is not an jQuery function used in this way. Load is for AJAX

Comment: Load is not for Ajax, please @Hurda refer to the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) You will see that Load is used to hook an even when something is done loading. You could use Load with an image. But, I have to agree with you that it's not appropriate either in the case that Anthony provides.

Comment: @Doak - I still thinks he ment http://api.jquery.com/load/ ajax load - it loads some content.
The actual method is chosen based on parameters - so we can't be sure. I'm just curious why you feel the need to try to correct me after 11 months?

Comment: Well, I'm sure between the two of you, your both right. It's been so long since I've touched jquery, I can't remember what load does.  I'm sure When I wrote the answer 25 months ago that I was under the impression that `load()` could be used to reload any window or document object. Like I said, I can't remember what it actually doe anymore.  I think overall I was trying to present an option that was simple and didn't require negotiating same-origin policies.

Comment: Actually, I think it's pretty ridiculous Hurda to assume which method I meant, since neither of them would actually accomplish what I was suggesting it would.  Why would I think that a method meant for ajax would reload an iframe any more than I would think that a method meant for event binding would reload it? If anything, I was probably thinking of pure js and the way that you use "onblah" for binding and "blah" to fire the event.  Either way, the method wouldn't reload the iframe, so I edited my answer.

Comment: You can't assign to a function call.

Answer (score 4):

```
var handle = setInterval(changeIframe, 30000);
var sites = ["google.com", "yahoo.com"];
var index = 0;

function changeIframe() {
  $('#frame')[0].src = sites[index++];
  index = index >= sites.length ? 0 : index;
}
```