# Dynamically Setting the Src Attribute of an Iframe while maintaining Cross-Browser Compatibility

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am going to create a Iframe which must update its contents dynamically (through the src attribute -  The Iframe will change its location every time a different button is clicked) to play different youtube videos that my company has created. The problem is that I saw that you can use jquery to achieve this. I am oblivious to jquery at the moment, but will take time to learn it.   For now, I need an answer. How do I use Jquery (or any alternative browser friendly method ) to Change the src Attribute of my Iframe?

```
<script runat="server">

</script>
<div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
    <table style="width: 960px" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="6">
                <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JZOxqVl5oP4"
                    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="VideoPlayer"></iframe>
            </td>
            <td style="Width: 130px">
                <img width="130px" src="./Images/Video_Logos/l_absa.gif" />
            </td>
...
```

Note that there are 10 buttons. The buttons are images, and I was planning to call different "Methods" for different videos to play.

I know about javascript's Document.GetElementById("VideoPlayer").SetAttribute("src","NEW LOCATION") within a function, but , lets face it. IE6 + 7 sucks.

Comment: Short answer: don't use an iframe =)

Comment: Because if there is a c# answer, I can also understand it :) im still a student though

Comment: http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a link. No need to mess around with JavaScript.

You will need to give the frame a name, that is how links target frames.

```
<a href="http://youtube.com/etc/etc" 
   target="name_of_frame">
       <img width="130" 
            src="./Images/Video_Logos/l_absa.gif" 
            alt="something" />
</a>
```

The width attribute takes an integer value (or an integer followed by a `%` character), not a CSS length. Get rid of the `px`.

The alt attribute on `<img>` elements is mandatory ([even in HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-1.html#general-guidelines))

Comment: <a href="http://www.google.com" target="VideoPlayer" /> <img width="130px" src="./Images/Video_Logos/l_absa.gif" alt="absa" /></a>

This is supposed to target my Iframe, but what it does is open the page in a new browser. Why does it do that?

Comment: Nevermind XD had the ID= attribute in my Iframe , instead of Name=

Answer (score 1):

From the answer given in:

[How do I dynamically change the content in an iframe using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554396/change-content-in-iframe-with-jquery)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var locations = ["http://webPage1.com", "http://webPage2.com"];
        var iframe = $('#frame');
        $(iframe).attr('src', locations[1]);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="frame"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would recommend not using an iFrame to play the YouTube, take a look at the Javascript Youtube API:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

Comment: Thanks. I am very time pressed at the moment, must have my site up in 3 hours. Does this method take very long to set up?

Comment: @Eon, never used it but seen it in use.  If it is going to take 3 hours do whatever and probably don't risk a new technique, then put it on a to do list to upgrade later.

Comment: Something to improve on! thanks! Got the answer above though , from @David Dorward