# Dynamically update iframe content in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe container inside the body section and a button.
Any click upon the button makes a call to server and fetches some html content.
Now I want the html content which comes as response from my server to be placed inside the iframe. Here is the code I am doing:-

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/myServer/getPage.htm";
    request.open('GET', serverURL + '?url=' + url, false);
    request.send(null);
    if(request.status == 200) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
        var resp = eval('(' + request.responseText + ')');
        var data = resp[0].data;
        //alert(data);
        var path = 'http://localhost:8080/test/about.html';
        $("#newPage").attr('src',data);
    }
```

On alerting data variable it is giving me correct html code but the last line is not working. I don't know where i am doing wrong. For testing purpose I placed path instead of data then it worked perfectly. Please help!

Comment: data variable looks like this:--------

<html>\n <head> \n <\/head> \n <body> \n  <div class=\"gamecontent\"> \n   <div class=\"caption\"> \n    <h1>About Me<\/h1> \n   <\/div> \n   <div class=\"test ui-helper-clearfix\">\n     Testing 1 2 3  . \n   <\/div> \n   <br />\n   <br />\n   <br />  \n  <\/div>\n <\/body>\n<\/html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is difference between string (javascript variable data here) and an actual html page. You might need to save your data variable in some html page and then update your iframe. I am not too sure about my solution. Check this out [How do I dynamically change the content in an iframe using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554396/change-content-in-iframe-with-jquery)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to save the data variable (which contains html code of desired page) can be saved into html file and loaded into iframe. The above mentioned url is good but its not what i am looking for

Comment: I have found out the error in your code but don't know how to correct it. Suppose your data var contains <html> ---something something--- </html> Then using $("#newPage").attr('src',data); means your source for iframe is <html> ---something something --- </html> which is not actually a html file and thats why you might be getting a 404 NOT FOUND error. Check it in your console. I think someone else here might help you