# Change Iframe SRC through select box Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to know, how can we change the SRC url for IFRAME through select box.

we have a following code.

**HTML CODE**

```
<select name="sign" size="1">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">Select Signature</option><option value="4ff42886$1$YT2.BF2.$241VJYgpUpWPD7p1Wjq5E1">Link Building India</option> 
</select>
```

**IFRAME CODE**

```
<iframe name="iframe2" src="signature.php?sign=" align="top" height="100%" width="95%" hspace="10" vspace="10" align="middle"></iframe>
```

I just want to update the src of Iframe2 according to the value of Select box like this

**Final code for IFRAME**  That to be change according to the select box.

```
<iframe name="iframe2" src="signature.php?sign=4ff42886$1$YT2.BF2.$241VJYgpUpWPD7p1Wjq5E1" align="top" height="100%" width="95%" hspace="10" vspace="10" align="middle"></iframe>
```

Thanks

Gun

Comment: This May Help You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554396/change-content-in-iframe-with-jquery or try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/rhpNc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a template and use that to re-render your `iframe` each time? You can do that since you know the parent the `iframe` resides in, right?

Something like..

```
var iframeHTMLTemplate = '<iframe ... name="blah" src="@src" />
```

And while appending to DOM..

```
$("select").change(function(){ // put a ID to select tag
  var url = "signature.php?sign="+$(this).val();

  var myIframe = $(iframeHTMLTemplate.replace('@src', url));

  container.append(myIframe);

});
```

Comment: how can we make it the code for re-render this function. should we place a button for refresh the Iframe, whenever i change the select box. becoz it's not working at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").change(function(){ // put a ID to select tag
  var url = "signature.php?sign="+$(this).val();

  $("iframe").attr("src",url); 

});
```