# Read Form Fields of IFRAME - Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, json, iframe

**My html page looks like below.. what i need done is if someone types something in ApplicantInfo1$FirstName field outside of IFRAME- I dont have any control on the url which is opened in Iframe. Is this possible using Json or Javascript .**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
First Name : 
<input name="ApplicantInfo1$FirstName" type="text" maxlength="30" id="ApplicantInfo1_FirstName" title="First Name" class="nonnumeric" minlength="2" style="width:200px;" /> 
<br />
<iframe id="progressive" src="https://www.progressivelp.com/onlineapplication/onlineapplication.aspx?sid=Metro2674957490&kid=1" width="940" height="1200" scrolling="no" style="border:none;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554396/change-content-in-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: @IvoJonkers: it seems like that answer only sets the URL of the iframe, which doesn't trigger the same origin policy.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible due to the same origin policy that browsers enforce.

Without that policy, anyone could write a web page that opens your online banking in an iframe and reads anything it wants from that HTML. I think we can agree that this would be a huge security risk, so that in general the same original policy (SOP) is a Good Thing.

A common way to work around this limitation is by introducing a proxy page on your server. This proxy page can then retrieve the remote web page on your behalf and return its contents to the browser. This ensures both HTMLs come from the same domain.