# switch the url for an iframe to a new one when you click a thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update the src="" of an iframe when I click through the thumbnails. This is what I have so far.

html

```
<div class="videoPopup"><span class="close">X close</span>
    <iframe width="600" height="400" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="vidTrigger"></div>
<div class="vidTrigger"></div>
<div class="vidTrigger"></div>
```

jQuery

```
var youtubevidId = ['SzsDHtzx6tI', 'BOQvtdXRtKw', 'gmIJoQV96PM'];

for (var i = 0; i <= youtubevidId.length; i++) {
    var iframeEmbed = ('http://www.youtube.com/embed/youtubevidId?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque');
}
$('.vidTrigger').click(function () {
    $('.videoPopup').show();
    $(iframe).attr(src, iframeEmbed);
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.videoPopup').hide();
});
```

I could probably have done something like this 
[How do I dynamically change the content in an iframe using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554396/change-content-in-iframe-with-jquery)

but I am trying to make the array items look little nicer. The string is a bit long. The only thing that changes in that is the youtube video id. So I thought I will take this route

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/mZh3c/3/

For me the js fiddle is acting a bit weird today. If it keeps on loading and nothing shows up just stop the pge from loading it will be there. Weird but its happening for me

Another major bug is it has to work on jquery 1.3.2 :-(. Which totally sucks

Comment: a great tool (faster to setup and in some cases better than jsFiddle) http://jsbin.com

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i like your iteration over youtubevidId and reasinging iframeEmbed every time...

Comment: first of all `iframeEmbed` variable is not visible for the click function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got you fiddle working, saw some mistake. The first one was your loop. It is doing nothing actually since the var is a single string (nothing change every iteration) and can be targeted inside the click function since you are declaring it inside the loop. But you can remove the loop, you don't need it.

You can select the cell of the array based on the index of the thumbnail clicked with that :

```
youtubevidId[$('.vidTrigger').index(this)]
```

Well, changing that will not change anything because you made a typo in the `.attr()` function. The first argument must be a string:

```
$(selector).attr('src', 'the link');
```

Also, the selector (when using `.attr()`) should be a string aswell:

```
$('iframe').attr('src', 'link');
```

If you combine what i said, remove the loop and changing that line :

```
$(iframe).attr(src, iframeEmbed);
```

to that :

```
$('iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ youtubevidId[$('.vidTrigger').index(this)] +'?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque');
```

Everything will work fine : http://jsfiddle.net/mZh3c/6/

Comment: @Karl--what you did is also pretty cool. I will keep this one in mind.  Thanks for doing this though

Comment: Actually what you did is indeed pretty good. I think I will just stick to this. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You forgot add quotes to `$('iframe')` and `'src'`. Also you inicialize `iframeEmbed` in for loop, so its not visible in `click` event

```
var youtubevidId = ['SzsDHtzx6tI', 'BOQvtdXRtKw', 'gmIJoQV96PM'];
var iframeEmbed;
for (var i = 0; i <= youtubevidId.length; i++) {
    iframeEmbed = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/youtubevidId?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque';
}
$('.vidTrigger').click(function () {
    $('.videoPopup').show();
    $('iframe').attr('src', iframeEmbed);
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.videoPopup').hide();
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mZh3c/5/)

**EDIT:** I just fixed some bugs in your code, but its still not work ... because of bad code logic, instead of checking `index`, there is easier way. Use `.data` to store video `id`:

HTML:

```
<div class="vidTrigger" data-video="SzsDHtzx6tI"></div>
<div class="vidTrigger" data-video="BOQvtdXRtKw"></div>
<div class="vidTrigger" data-video="gmIJoQV96PM"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.vidTrigger').click(function () {
    $('.videoPopup').show();
    $('iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+$(this).data('video')+'?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque');
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.videoPopup').hide();
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mZh3c/7/)